# Store Events List from Google Calendar Node.js Example in Express.js Application

Tags: node.js, express, google-calendar-api

Being a javascript/node.js/express.js newbie, I'm banging my head on this one.  Looking at "[Google Calendar API Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs#notes)", I've been able to sucessfully print a list of upcoming events when running `node quickstart.js`.  I'd now like to present this data in the browser by passing it into the view renderer.  I've copied over the code from quickstart.js into my *routes/calendar.js* file.  This is what *routes/calendar.js* currently looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json';

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

function listEvents(auth) {
  var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
  calendar.events.list({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }

    var events = response.items;

    if (events.length == 0) {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var event = events[i];
        var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
      }
    }
  });
}

/* GET events listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
    // Google Calendar API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), listEvents);
  });

  // TODO:  How can I pass 'events' from 'listEvents' into the view renderer?
  res.render('calendar', { title: 'TS Calendar', current: 'calendar', events: events });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I visit http://localhost:3000/calendar in my browser, I do get an error about 'events' not being defined, but my console does print out the calendar events, so I know it's working on at least some level.

It seems to me to be just a mess of callbacks, and I can't quite wrap my head around how to extract/store `var events = response.items;` from within `listEvents()` so it's usable within `router.get()`.  Any suggestions?  A good example would be fantastic.

Also, for bonus points, I'm a little weary of including all this logic/code into the *routes/calendar.js* file.  Is there a more expressjs-esque or appropriate place for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking I was in the wrong mindset here.  Instead, I went with client-side javascript and used the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) for that.  I've made progress going this route, but I have a feeling I'm going to quickly find out it's not going to lend itself nicely to a kiosk application where a keyboard isn't present to authenticate.  Might need to ask that question when I get to that point.